# Text color in woocommerce lead time plugin in cart not changing

Tags: css, colors

I am trying to bring more attention to the fact a product has a delivery time longer than normal in my cart.
Therefore i installed "woocommerce lead time" plugin. This helped a bit because i get less emails about: "why is my order not here yet", but the text color in the cart is grey and i`d like it to be red to realy draw attention.

I figured it out what to change and where to put it, i thought, via the inspect element in Chrome, this made my lead time text red.

But when i apply this same code to my css it does not change the color. **I think it is being override by something but can`t figure this out.**

Wordpress with Flatsome theme, and a child theme. I applied the code to the main Flatsome theme because the css cannot be found in the child file structure which sucks also because i dont want to do it everytime there`s an update. But thats an other thing.
[Lead time should be red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRiru.jpg)

The website is: [Fantasy Giftshop](https://fantasygiftshop.nl/product/anne-stokes-air-elemental-wizard/)

If you add this product to the cart you can see what i mean, text is still grey, and not realy drawing attention.

**This is what i tried**

I thought i fixed it by inspecting the item in Chrome, there i added ;color:red to the code and it worked.
Then i whent to the css that it pointed to and pasted that exact code, uploaded, nothing changed.
I tried to use "#ff0000" instead of "red" but this also didn`t work. I realy thougt this was an easy fix haha XD

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Failed to reproduce: The text shown to me was red, not gray. Also, please refrain from adding irrelevant information to the question and include *your code* in a minimal, reproducible example instead.

Comment: I am sorry you are right, it is already fixed, there is some delay in the showing of the code i guess.. I will not over-informate in future topics and i will put my code in in, thank you anyways. Mod, you can close this topic.